# How to setup Grunt.js with different inputs?

Tags: javascript, compression, minify, gruntjs

Im using Grunt.js to concat/minify files - but would like to use 1 common grunt.js file to concat/compress files in multiple directories for different websites. What would be the best way to do this?

I was hoping I could setup 2 different tasks like this:

```
//ATG INTL US (excluding VIR)
    concat1: {
      dist: {
        src: ['<banner:meta.banner>', '../js/plugins/jquery.tools.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js','../js/plugins/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.jcarousel.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.cookie.js','../js/plugins/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.min.js','../js/lib/modernizr/modernizr.custom.39125.js','../js/plugins/jquery.select2.min.js'],        dest: '../js/common/plugins.js'
      }
    },
    // ATG INTL US (VIR ONLY)
    concat2: {
      dist: {
        src: ['<banner:meta.banner>', '../js/plugins/jquery.tools.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js','../js/plugins/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.jcarousel.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.cookie.js','../js/plugins/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.min.js','../js/lib/modernizr/modernizr.custom.39125.js','../js/plugins/jquery.select2.min.js','../include/js/plugins/jquery-ui.selectmenu.js'],        dest: '../js/common/plugins.js'
      }
    },
```

Then register the different task when I want to run it:

```
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'lint qunit mincss concat1 min');
```

But that doesnt seem to be working, Ive heard about watch but not sure if that would work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I can setup different directories:

```
concat: {
      //ATG INTL US (excluding VIR)
      atgintlus: {
        src: ['<banner:meta.banner>', '../js/plugins/jquery.tools.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js','../js/plugins/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.jcarousel.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.cookie.js','../js/plugins/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.min.js','../js/lib/modernizr/modernizr.custom.39125.js','../js/plugins/jquery.select2.min.js'],        dest: '../js/common/plugins.js'
      },
      // ATG INTL US (VIR ONLY)
      atgintlvir: {
        src: ['<banner:meta.banner>', '../js/plugins/jquery.tools.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js','../js/plugins/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.jcarousel.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js','../js/plugins/jquery.cookie.js','../js/plugins/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.min.js','../js/lib/modernizr/modernizr.custom.39125.js','../js/plugins/jquery.select2.min.js','../include/js/plugins/jquery-ui.selectmenu.js'],        dest: '../js/common/plugins.js'
      }
    },
```

Then register different tasks:

```
 // ATG INTL US task.
  // Run in Command line using Grunt atgintlus
  grunt.registerTask('atgintlus', ['lint','mincss','concat:atgintlus', 'min:atgintlus']);

  // VIR US task.
  // Run in Command line using Grunt atgintlvir
  grunt.registerTask('atgintlvir', ['lint','mincss','concat:atgintlvir', 'min:atgintlvir']);
```

Works like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

Right, so what you've done is created a "multi task" (a task with multiple targets). Looks like you got it going, but you may want to have a look at a [series of vids](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9WXnwy2C00) I made on grunt.js to possibly help you further grok grunt.js and here's the one on [tasks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRWhjOxG7EE).